# how to access database from web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webmethod

How to access database from a web service in ASP.NET? i have a `[webmethod]` in WebServices class and this is not calling in code file:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet Populate(string con, string sql)
{
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(con, sql);
    DA.Fill(DS);
    Return DS;
}
```

Comment: Puting Database access directly in Webmethod ? Please first create a Data Access Layer and use it.

Comment: have you get any error ?

Comment: @Massanu infact he can put database access perfectly in webmethod

Comment: @mekici I dont say it will not work, I just say that its really bad practice to put database access directly in WebMethod

Comment: @Massanu question was not about best practice

Answer (score 1):

Check you sql cmd is not blank.
and write as
 `SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);`